# Populate array from string occurrences in text

Tags: javascript, php, regex, laravel

I need to populate an array with all the "specific occurrences" string from a text. Imagine I have the text:

- "Hi, my name is Bob, I am 20 years old and like cats. [lots of text here] Hi, my name is
  Dylan, I am 25 years old and like dogs. [lots of text here] Hi, my name is Tambourine, I
  am 30 years old and like turtles". [lots of text here]

So I would need a looping that searches for "Hi, mas name is" and get the information until the period/dot. So my output would be something like:

- array[0] -> "Hi, my name is Bob, I am 20 years old and like cats."
- array[1] -> "Hi, my name is Dylan, I am 20 years old and like dogs."
- array[3] -> "Hi, my name is Tambourine, I am 20 years old and like turtles."

Until now I only could find the index from occurrences but can not populate the array with the string, only the index.

Thank you.

ps: the text is extracted from a PHP file so I am using PHP for security and limitations reasons

my code so far:

```
  $html = $file;
  $needle = "\$table->";
  $lastPos = 0;
  $positions = array();
  $positions2 = array();


  while (($lastPos = strpos($html, $needle, $lastPos))!== false) {
    $positions[] = $lastPos;
    $lastPos = $lastPos + strlen($needle);
 }
```

Comment: share your code what you have done so far

Comment: Sorry, done. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex to capture all sentences.

```
[A-Z][^.]+\.?
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/BTozgw/1)**

Try this PHP codes,

```
$s = "Hi, my name is Bob, I am 20 years old and like cats. Hi, my name is Dylan, I am 25 years old and like dogs. Hi, my name is Tambourine, I am 30 years old and like turtles";
preg_match_all('/[A-Z][^.]+\.?/', $s, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Prints,

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Hi, my name is Bob, I am 20 years old and like cats.
            [1] => Hi, my name is Dylan, I am 25 years old and like dogs.
            [2] => Hi, my name is Tambourine, I am 30 years old and like turtles
        )

)
```

If you're coding it in Javascript, here is a demo in JS,

```js
var s = "Hi, my name is Bob, I am 20 years old and like cats. Hi, my name is Dylan, I am 25 years old and like dogs. Hi, my name is Tambourine, I am 30 years old and like turtles"
console.log(s.match(/[A-Z][^.]+\.?/g))
```

Comment: Maybe I can not do with php split because I wrote only part of the text, there's more text after the "dots/periods". But I get it with the regex anwser. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with 
**Using php `explode()`:**

```
$string = "Hi, my name is Bob, I am 20 years old and like cats. Hi, my name is Dylan, I am 25 years old and like dogs. Hi, my name is Tambourine, I am 30 years old and like turtles";
print_r (explode(".",$string));
```

**Using Regex:**

```
$string = "Hi, my name is Bob, I am 20 years old and like cats. Hi, my name is Dylan, I am 25 years old and like dogs. Hi, my name is Tambourine, I am 30 years old and like turtles";
$arr = preg_split('/[ap]\.m\.(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\./', $string);
print_r($arr);
```

Comment: Maybe I can not do with php explode because I wrote only part of the text, there's more text after the "dots/periods". But I just test it with the regex and it works exactly how I need. Really thank you. Now I need to study regex so I can finish it, but so far it is perfect.

Comment: @JeúCasulo Welcome, Keep Coding :)

Comment: By the way, I am giving the "right answer" for Pushpesh Kumar Rajwanshi cause he anwserd it first. But I really thank you

Comment: @JeúCasulo No worries bro